# Please Help I am Stucked in Between the Application

Tags: c#-4.0, user-interface, windows-forms-designer

i am Explaining the whole question:

I will take 2 forms, 3 text box and 2 buttons .

In 1st form i have draged 1 button and 2 textbox.
Now when i will enter some value and click on button . then one new 2nd form will appear with one button and 1 textbox . Now i have to enter the value in textbox in the new 2nd form. Now the first should be disable till I click the button on the 2nd form or close the 2nd form. and after the 2nd form is closed or the first form should get the focus. And if clicked on the button at the 2nd form then also the 2nd form should be closed and 1st form should get the focus.

Please help ... I am stucked in between the application..

Comment: where is the code ? What have you tried ? What is not working ?

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished in Form1 using code like this for the button click handler:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 f2 = new Form2();
        f2.ShowDialog(); // <-- Form1 will be inaccessible until "f2" is closed
    }
}
```

Over in Form2, you have:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK;
    }
}
```

But you didn't really say what was supposed to be happening with the TextBoxes...